# UITableView error when converting to Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, swift2

Updating an old app from swift 2.2 to swift 4. I have to use swift 3 as a stepping stone. I converted to 3 but come across the following error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IndexPath' and 'Int`

The code is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 || indexPath == 1 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NFL", sender: self)
    }

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 1 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AFL", sender: self)
    }

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 2 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FAI", sender: self)
    }

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 3 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "IPA", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error in Swift 3 and not 2.2? I tried to force it into an "Int" but don't think I was going about it the right way.

Comment: The phrase `indexPath == 1` wouldn't have compiled in Swift 2.2 either, so you are not really telling us the truth here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexPath` contains `row` and `section`

you need to specify if you want `indexPath.row` or `indexPath.section`

if you actually meant `indexPath.row`, your full code should look like:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NFL", sender: self)
        }


        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AFL", sender: self)
        }

        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FAI", sender: self)
        }

        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "IPA", sender: self)
        }
}
```

---

**Tips:**

You don't need to cast to `NSIndexPath`

For this comparison purpose, you should use a `switch` statement instead of many `if`statements.

If `indexPath.row == 1` it is going to performSegue twice with different results.

Comment: The logic in this answer (and probably the original code) has a big flaw. The 2nd `if` will result in two segues being performed if row is 1. And the use of `if else` would be better here.

Answer (score 1):

Beacause indexPath return `IndexPath` in Swift 4 and `(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row` returning `Int` so you can't force to equal .Also you don't even to use indexpath like `indexPath as NSIndexPath`. `indexPath.row` is enough